# 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randomVariable''

Tags: python

I have got 2 files which are imported to a main file, and are ran.

When I run it I keep getting the error:

```
dice_sides = random_var.randomVariable()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randomVariable'
>>>
```

My code: Main file:

```
import random, random_var, dice_roll

dice = [4, 6, 12]

def main():
    dice_sides = random_var.randomVariable()
    dice_roll.diceRoll(dice_sides)

main()
```

Random_var file:

```
import random, task_one # import modules and file to be used in program

dice = [4, 6, 12] # declare list

def randomVariable(): # function

    try: # tries this expression
        dice_sides = int(input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: "))
    except ValueError: # if user entered anything other than an integer
        print("You did not enter an integer. Program restarting.")
        task_one.main() # restarts, by getting the main function from "task_one" file

    return dice_sides; # returns variable so it can be used in other functions
```

Dice_roll file:

```
import random, task_one

dice = [4, 6, 12]
def diceRoll(dice_sides):

    if dice_sides in dice:
        diceThrown = random.randrange(1, dice_sides)
        print(dice_sides, " sided dice, score ", diceThrown)
    else:
        print("Number is invalid. Please choose either 4, 6 or 12. ")
        task_one.main()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you trying this in an interactive interpreter?  If so, restart it (and make sure you saved the file in your editor).  The interpreter caches modules and reuses them when they are imported, so changes aren't picked up.

Comment: I done that, but it still comes up with the error.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem on my machine - print dir(random_var) inside the main() function and paste the output

Comment: `ImportError: No module named random_var` I even have that file saved inside the same directory as my main file.

Comment: does random_var have a .py extension?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that `random_var` isn't what you think it is.

If you are running this in an interactive interpreter, close and restart it to ensure that the module gets reloaded.

Beyond that, make sure you've saved `random_var.py`, that its file name is correct (including capitalization), and that it's been saved where `import random_var` is looking for it (i.e. that you haven't ended up with two `random_var.py` files in different directories).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import random
from random_var import randomVariable
from dice_roll import diceRoll

dice = [4, 6, 12]

def main():
    dice_sides = randomVariable()
    diceRoll(dice_sides)

main()
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just came up with the error `ImportError: cannot import name randomVariable`

Comment: are all files in the same directory?